# Use jQuery .click() on AJAX posted content button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select which runs an AJAX function. This function returns a form with a button. Now I'd like to assign a function to this button with jQuery's `.click()` (or `.on()`).

E.g.

```
<select id='test'>
    <option val='1'>...</option>
    ...
</select>

/* Empty and filled with AJAX call */
<div id="ajax">
     /* FOLLOWING THE CONTENT RETURNED BY THE AJAX CALL */
     /* Won't work (see script below) */
     <input type="button" id="button" value="button" />

     /* will work */
     <input type="button" value="button" onclick="clickMe()" />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#test').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        ...
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    /* DOESN'T WORK */
    alert('click')
});

function clickMe(){
    /* WORKS */
    alert('click')
};
```

Is there a way to "enable" the AJAX result?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/  and scroll where it talks about **Direct and delegated events** and the *Delegated Events* example with `TR`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the event to highest element before the dynamic form using the `.on()` function with a selector that matches your button(s).

This will attached the event to all current ***and future*** matching elements.

```
$("#ajax").on("click", "#myButtonId", function(){
    // On click code here.
});
```

Comment: Don't go that far to `body` the OP already has a static element ID

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks, was actually revising right after I posted it :D

Comment: How to get the id of the clicked button inside the function? `$(this).id` doesn't work

Comment: @Perocat Use: `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: @Perocat just use `this.id`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**`event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method, since the buttons are created dynamically . You can use jQuery [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to listen the button.

```
$("#ajax").on("click","#button",function(){
    alert('click')
});
```

Otherwise the event doesn't bind to the dynamically generated item.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Pranav C Balan, that is a way to solve the problem. And I propose another way:
after the ajax response, you can bind the event in the added markup. Like:

```
$.get("test.jsp",function(response){
    $("#ajax").children("#button").click(function(){
       // click callback goes here...
    });
},"html")
```

Tips: do not nest the callback more two func. That will make the spaghetti code.To solve this you can use the promise in jquery. [Here is the doc.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (JXHR object)

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery's `.on()` to listen for the event bubbling to the parent element. This means it will still fire the event for elements that are added *after* you have set the event listener.

```
$('#ajax').on('click','#button',function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

See the jQuery documentation for on: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Similar answer is different

Comment: Similar answer was revised before you posted this.